# C# Serial Port Receiving Data in the form of Symbols

Tags: c#, serial-port, communication

i am having a arduino RFID`enter code here` reader which send me the data through serail port but i

do not receive data in the correct form like 0001685839 025,47439

please help my code is this

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;

class PortDataReceived
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM3");

        mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
        mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
        mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
        mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        mySerialPort.RtsEnable = true;

        mySerialPort.DataReceived += new     SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

        mySerialPort.Open();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadKey();
        mySerialPort.Close();
    }

    private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender,SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
        Console.Write(indata);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you receive anything at all? Have you tried RtsEnable = false?

Comment: yes tried but still receiving symbols and English characters

Answer (score 0):

What data do you receive?
There is a notion of buffer for com port. You can end up with two read events in case when data does not fit port buffer.

You can try something like this:

```c#
int bytesToRead = sp.BytesToRead;
var bytes = new byte[bytesToRead];

sp.Read(bytes, 0, bytesToRead);
var indata = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)

sp.DiscardInBuffer();
sp.DiscardOutBuffer();
```

Comment: i am receiving data in symbols  and English words instead of numbers